# SQL count ocurrences within time periods

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I recently started up working with Access database in a project at my work (hospital) and got lots of useful tips from this site. However, I have now a problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

I have a table containing treatment dates (as well as other data) for lots of patients. My task is to count the number of treatments given within each week (and possibly month/quarter/year as well). The treatment dates are located in the column 'TreatDate' in the table 'Data'.

I have used `DatePart` to separate out year and week number as:

```
SELECT 
    DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]) AS Year, DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]) AS Week 
FROM Data 
ORDER BY DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]),DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]);
```

Which gives me:

```
    Year   Week
    2006   16
    2006   16
    2006   16
    2006   17
    2006   17
    2006   18
    2006   19
    2006   19
    2006   19
    ...    ...
```

How do I count the number of occurances in each week in order to get something like:

```
    Year  Week  N
    2006  16    3
    2006  17    2
    2006  18    1
    2006  19    3
    ...   ...   ...
```

Best regards,
Mattias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]) AS Year, 
       DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]) AS Week, 
       COUNT(*) as N
FROM Data 
GROUP BY DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]),DatePart('ww',[TreatStart])
ORDER BY DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]),DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]);
```

The output will be:

```
Year  Week  N
2006  16    3
2006  17    2
2006  18    1
2006  19    3
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the `group by` on the same values by which you want count  and add the `count` aggregate function to get the total count of the appointments at that given group.

```
SELECT DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]) AS Year, DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]) AS Week , COUNT(*) As N
FROM Data 
GROUP BY DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]),DatePart('ww',[TreatStart])
ORDER BY DatePart('yyyy',[TreatStart]),DatePart('ww',[TreatStart]);
```